# How to align a list of 2D images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a series of 2D, grayscale images of different sizes (they are extracted silhouettes of the same person). I would like to be able to align them all, so that all images are the same size.

The transformations I would like to use are only: scaling, and translation. I'm trying to use OpenCV with `cv2.estimateRigidTransform`, but it also introduces rotations.

Two sample images are the following:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please show us the images, it would help to understand your question

Comment: @Jigsaw I edited the issue adding images. I was also thinking that it would be possible to align them minimizing the least square error of the difference. But I don't see nothing like this in OpenCV